# Listviews and onClickListener with focus issue

Tags: android, onclick, focus, setfocus

I have setup a very simply list view which when you click on row it will then open up another fragment. If I set up the onclick inside of my list views on Item click listener it will happily work. But because I have multiple options I decided to build the onClickListener on another class then set it with one line. The problem is now I have to double click in order to get it to work. Please see below.

Inside of the list view this method is happy to accept one click.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

 // code

 }
 });
```

If I setup like this then it requires two clicks, but I don't know why?

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new InputContactNumber());
```

Comment: post more code like `InputContactNumber` and `adapter`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use view.setOnClickItemListener instead of view.setOnClickLisener.

Answer (score 0):

can you please put your Class code in which you declared the event 
it seems to me that you have to directly call the Methode that you declared in the class to handle the event 
Example :

```
    view.setOnClickListener(new InputContactNumber().myListnerEventHandler); 
//where myListnerEventHandler is the Methode declared to handel onClick Event in the class
```

Comment: I just find it strange how its works but I need to double click

Comment: did you try what i told you?